# can't open an URL neither with BeautifulSoup or request

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

i'm trying to open an URL with 2 kinds of options (that already worked for me in with different sites) but both of them aren't working.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main():
    url = "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=black+watch&s=review-rank&qid=1568506943&ref=sr_st_review-rank"
    client = ureq(url)
    page = client.read()
    client.close()
    amazon_soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    # amazon_soup = get_page(url)
    print(amazon_soup)


def get_page(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        if not response.ok:
            print(('server responded', response.status_code))
        else:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    except:
        print("oops")
        requests.exceptions.ConnectionError
        return

    return soup


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

it suppose to print the html code for this searching but i keep getting "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable "
even if i try the other way (that marked as a comment for now) i get 503 Error

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach proper user-agent header to your request, have a look at this snippet
Websites like amazon and reddit expect you to have proper useragent or else they'll respond with 503.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main():
    url = "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=black+watch&s=review-rank&qid=1568506943&ref=sr_st_review-rank"
    req = Request(url)
    req.add_header('user-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.20 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.672.2 Safari/534.20')
    client = urlopen(req)
    page = client.read()
    client.close()
    amazon_soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    # amazon_soup = get_page(url)
    print(amazon_soup)


def get_page(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        if not response.ok:
            print(('server responded', response.status_code))
        else:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    except:
        print("oops")
        requests.exceptions.ConnectionError
        return

    return soup


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thanks man that's the solution (more or less)      do you know maybe how to pass the limited search lines amount?    (i can search "xbox3" only about 1000 times per day)